# Cambiar cadena de conexión en app.config de mi aplicación en tiempo de ejecución c#

Tags: c#, app.config

He buscado esta pregunta por mucho lugares en la web y no he encontrado una respuesta definitiva y que me sirva.

Intento cambiar mi cadena de conexión con este código:

```
string localhost = "MiServidor";
String cadenaNueva = "Data Source =" + localhost+ "; Initial Catalog = 
MiBD; Integrated Security = True";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString = cadenaNueva;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Al parecer se cambia correctamente, pero hago la prueba escribiendo un servidor erróneo y aún así sigue con la misma cadena, en que estoy fallando? Tienen una solución más completa?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: dime que no lo estas probando en modo debug, si no sobre un ejecutable que no sobreescribe la configuracion cada vez que compila

Comment: @gbianchi Al principio lo estaba probando en modo debug, luego leí tu mismo comentario y lo probé con el ejecutable y tengo el mismo problema

Comment: Hola. Prueba a acceder por nombre de tu cadena de conexión en vez de por índice de array. `config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["micadenaconexion"].ConnectionString = cadenaNueva;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He hecho una prueba con tu codigo usando EF, y me he dado cuenta de una cosa.
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings tiene dos cadenas de conexión:

- la primera es: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
- la segunda es la cadena de conexión que uso para conectarme a mi base de datos.

Si pones:
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[**1**].ConnectionString = cadenaNueva;

A mi me funciona bien, me modifica la cadena de conexión, cierras la aplicación y la vuelves a abrir y ya no carga los datos y da error.

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Excelente me sirvió muchas gracias,lo que no entiendo es por qué me sale dos cadenas de conexión si en el archivo app.config solo tengo escrita una cadena...

Comment: También tengo otra pregunta, mi proyecto es en 3 capas, "capaDatos", "capaNegocio", "capaPresentación", y el proyecto inicial... Cuando intento acceder a  unas claves que tengo el archivo app.config de la capaDatos, siempre lee es el archivo app.config del proyecto inicial, a que se debe esto?

Comment: La primera cadena que a mi aparece es una conexión al sql server local que instala el Visual Studio. En el caso de los proyectos MVC, te crea la gestión de los usuarios en esta misma base de datos, pero no se por que muy bien.

Comment: Para que la cadena de conexión no coja el proyecto inicial, en la cadena de conexión puedes poner lo siguiente:     <add name="miDatos.Properties.Settings.DatosConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVIDORBD\basedatos1;Initial Catalog=DatosPrueba;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;Password=YYY" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> Si te das cuenta empieza por miDatos que es mi proyecto que realiza todas las consultas sql. En este proyecto tiene que existir esta cadena también.